# Showing a View after ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit

In UIKit I have a single View created in Xcode.
[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04uBN.png)
How can I present or show that from View a UIViewController class after a button is hit? Because present(vc, animated: true) only works for ViewControllers...

Comment: Why don't you link your view to a view controller to do that?

Comment: Do you mean to set the file as the file owner and create a IBOutlet?

Comment: Yes usually the view is there to be seen but what controls it or what's inside, is the view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must first connect it to the view property of some controller, and then present that controller

For this:

1. Open your `View` (.xib) file
2. Select "File's Owner" in left section pane
3. Select "Show the Attribute inspector" in right section pane
4. Enter the class name of the ViewController that you want to attach this view to (for example: `MyViewController`)
5. Select "Show the Connections Inspector" in right section pane
6. Connect view outlet to the your view

After that you can initialize your class and present in somewhere after tap/click